# How to manally lookup "@string/..." style references in custom android XML

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have something like the following custom XML in `res/xml/widgets.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <widget name="car" color="mauve">Car Name: @string/car_name</widget>
</root>
```

and `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="car_name">Ford Model-T</string>
</resources>
```

Since I am using `getResources().getXml()` to parse the XML manually, the embedded string `@string/car_name` is not dereferenced automatically by Android. How do I do it myself (without a lot of annoying reflection code)? This is to say, I would like a method that gives me back the string `Car Name: Ford Model-T`, assuming I have already parsed `Car Name: @string/car_name` using the XMLPullParser. Surely the methods Android itself uses are visible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my solution should work. Did you try it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search through your XML String, find every @string/str_name , and then find related string to `str_name` by this:
`String relatedString = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("str_name", "string", getPackageName()));`
then replace `@string/str_name` with `relatedString`

Done!

Comment: Sorry for not responding. This method is not as general as I would like, but it is more or less what I used, so I guess you get the checkmark. In the end, I abandoned parameterized strings, and now I just specify things like `@string/str_name` in XML. In this case, the string ID can be found via `getResources().getIdentifier(str.substring(1), "string", getPackageName())`, assuming the first character is `@`. (This also dereferences `@str_name` to `string/str_name`.)